# Where is the 'Query Options' command in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, database, mail-merge

I want to attempt a mail merge by category.
Was it removed from the app?

Comment: See [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officedevdocs/archive/2012/02/06/insert-database-query-results-as-a-table-programmatically-in-word-2010.aspx), among others.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the [Filter](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/use-mail-merge-to-create-and-print-letters-and-other-documents-HA101857701.aspx) option in the **Mail Merge Recipients** dialog is what you're looking for:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

As you can see above, the drop-down menus in the column headers are also useful for basic filtering. You might also find [this YouTube tutorial video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jlhAnq1F4Gk) helpful.